# Question on Big O notation scaling factor

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have 2 algorithms to do something (eg search a list) one has linear complexity and the other has log complexity (O(log n).  If I am comparing operation on 100 and 1000 units, do I say the linear algorithm has scaling factor x10?

How do I express the log algo scaling factor?  eg 100 items takes 2 seconds, 1000 items takes 3 seconds.  The log of 1000 is 3, the log of 100 is 2.  So what is the scale factor?  x1.5?

I can see that the growth in time is logarithmic.  Or do you just say the scaling factor is logarithmic?  But what would you calculate if example was comparing 100 to 1000 items?

Comment: You've defined this concept of a scale factor, and possibly confused yourself by doing so. If one thing takes 3 seconds and another takes 2, the ratio of those times is 1.5. If you choose to call that a "scaling factor" you're welcome to. Beware that just because an algorithm is O(n) time, it doesn't necessarily follow that the ratio between the time for 1000 and the time for 100 will be the same as the ratio between the time for 10k and the time for 1k. Possibly what you're looking for is, respectively, the coefficient of the linear term and the coefficient of the log term.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: But even that doesn't necessarily translate into time.

Comment: @Jason: exactly, it's just the term that dominates time in the limit at infinity. 1000 is not close to infinity, so the behaviour at infinity is in principle irrelevant to behaviour around 1000.

Comment: A constant "factor" already assumes linear growth (only in a linear runtime will processing an input of 100N take 100 times longer than processing an input of N).  The concept simply doesn't apply to any other growth patterns, unless you're allowed to introduce N into the factor itself.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Not unless the bound is tight. Bubblesort is `O(n^2)` but it's also `O(n^3)`.

Comment: @Jason: yes, if for example the coefficient of the linear term is 0 in the O(n) case then you'd need to look further in order to get a satisfactory description of the growth. It might not grow at all in the limit: it might be O(1) but just appear linear for numbers as small as 1000.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Yes, we are in agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it as "it scales in a linear/quadratic/cubic/logarithmic/exponential fashion", I wouldn't reference the exact scaling factor at all. The big O isn't about specific times, it is a way to put algorithms into certain classes, ie. linear class, logarithmic class etc.

The point isn't about making assumptions on the exact runtime (this is influenced by many details and depends entirely on the machine the algorithm is running on) but to be able to put it in relative terms, so you can say that an O(n²) algorithm will be slower than O(n), O(log n) at a glance.

Comment: Actually, you can only say that in the limit that an `O(n^2)` algorithm is "slower" than an `O(log n)` algorithm. The constant on the `log n` could be ridiculously large (or the constant on the `n^2` could be ridiculously small).

Comment: You are right of course, but it should be proveable that there will be an n for such a case that c * n^2 > d * log n. The growing rate on a logarithmic algorithm can't be modified by a constant in way that it always will be growing faster than a quadratic algorithm. If you keep your input small enough, the c*n^2 can be faster, I don't doubt that. Those are specific cases however.

Answer (score 1):

Your question presupposes that "scaling factor" is meaningful for any order of complexity other than linear and this is simply not the case. But even for linear it's kind of meaningless. See, just because an algorithm is `O(n)` doesn't mean that an input of size `2x` is going to take twice as "long" as an input of size `x`.

Your question also presupposes the common misconception that order of complexity is translatable into time. It is not. Order of complexity is useful for asymptotic analysis of algorithms, not for measuring time to completion give a particular input size.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't compute a numeric scaling factor from just the Big O complexity because the Big O complexity omits the coefficients and constants that are critical to computing the scaling factor.

If algorithm A has an actual complexity of `(1/1000) * n + 100` while algorithm B has an actual complexity of `100*log(n) + 1`, algorithm A is O(n) while algorithm B is O(log(n)).  However, when you go from an n of 100 to an n of 1000, A goes from a cost of 100.1 to 101 while B goes from a cost of 201 to 301.  Algorithm A's actual runtime increased by only 1% while algorithm B's actual runtime increased by 50%.

Big O notation is designed to tell you how something scales as n goes to infinity.  When you're looking at an actual non-infinite range, it's entirely possible that the algorithm with a better Big O notation is slower and scales less efficiently than the algorithm with the worse Big O notation.  For a sufficiently large n, the algorithm with the better Big O notation will eventually win.  But there is no guarantee that the crossover point is actually within the realm of what is expected for any given purpose.